# Android App only allows to take pictures but not recording videos

Tags: android, android-webview

I created a WebView-based Android app.
When user clicks on the <kbd>Browse</kbd> button in a web page, a dialog appears that offers to choose between camera and files saved on the phone. When the camera is choosed, a photo can be taken that immediately uploads to the server. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with videos. When camera opens, there are no controls that allow to switch between taking photos and recording a video. It only allows to take photos.

These are my permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Is it necessary to add more permissions to control the video functionality of the camera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your permissions are fine, you don't need more to record video. If you are opening camera with MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE it will take pictures, for videos you need MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE. 
Here's relevant info:
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics#TaskCaptureIntent